# Repetir numero a cada contagem

Tags: php, loop, for, while

Como eu faço isso em php, por favor me ajudem:

( A cada 3 vezes )

```
0 = 0
1 = 0
2 = 0

3 = 1
4 = 1
5 = 1

6 = 2
7 = 2
8 = 2
```

Assim por diante .. Este é um exemplo simples do que gostaria de fazer, pois na verdade gostaria de implementar um menu de distribuição de processos onde existem 2 coordenadores e um diretor, mas para simplificar dei este exemplo simples acima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixo abaixo uma solução em javascript para que seja testável aqui no site. A ideia é usar o operador `%` (modulo) para verificar quando incrementar a variável que está a direita da igualdade, o módulo será igual a 0 somente nos múltiplos do intervalo desejado, por exemplo se o intervalo for 3, o modulo de `i` será igual a 0 quando `i` será 3, 6, 9 ... Veja [aqui](https://www.matematica.pt/faq/modulo-numero.php) mais explicações sobre o calculo do módulo se você não é familiarizado com o mesmo.

```js
let repetir = 9, 
    current = -1,
    intervalo = 3;

for(let i = 0; i < repetir; i++){
  if(i % intervalo === 0)
    current++;
    
  console.log(`${i} = ${current}`);
}
```

E aqui a tradução do mesmo em PHP:

```
$repetir = 9;
$current = -1;
$intervalo = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $repetir; $i++){
  if($i % $intervalo == 0)
    $current++;
    
    echo "$i = $current <br />";
}
```